# Has Anyone Tried FastReport .Net before?

Tags: .net, reporting

I'm looking for reporting solution for .net, my company has used Crystal Reports XI (and its Server edition) and SQL Server Reporting Services for our previous projects. However we're going to develop a new product and we want a fast, easily deployed/managed assemblies,programmable report document object, and has runtime report designer. I've tried the trial of FastReport.Net, it seems ok but it will be better if someone here has experience & issues with FastReport.Net.  And how about other products (ActiveReports, Telerik Reporting, etc) ?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using FastReport.Net in a WPF application I'm currently developing and I can say that it's a good reporting solution. I've started using it since it was in beta and then it had a couple of small line-rendering bugs, but even those could be solved if I'd change the dimensions of my columns a bit. In the current version, it seems that they've eliminated those bugs and I'm pretty happy with the product.

Answer (score 3):

We've used ActiveReports, XtraReports, and Telerik Reporting as well as played with a few others.  My usual preference for client projects is either AR or XR for Windows projects and XR for web projects.  But none of them come with the enterprise-class "server" features like Crystal Server or SSRS, so if you need that, look into [Universal Report Server](http://www.versareports.com).

Comment: Thanks for your info, but for this project we'll only use standard reporting.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend Active Reports for .net/asp.net (http://www.datadynamics.com/default.aspx) Especially if you want to export to PDF.

Its great for creating reports and reports as subreports with reports.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using fast report since more than 4-5 years, and it's the best reporting tool I have used in my life (compared to Oracle RB, Rave, CrystalReport, QuickReport and others I don't remember).

It's very easy to use, very fast and you could build very complex reports with easy steps.

I use it mainly with Delphi, the product is great, .Net version is newer but going well

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'll stick with FastReport.Net

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [myDBR](http://www.mydbr.com) a web-based reporting solution that works with MS SQL Server and mySQL. Reports are created as stored procedures in the database and can be easily formatted for your needs.

For example creating a chart is done by just adding one line of code to your stored procedure.

myDBR also allows you to track the usage of your reports, so that you know which reports are most popular and which reports take the longest to run.